# Java - finding a parent of a node in a Binary Tree? (converted from a general tree)

Tags: java, traversal

I have a binary tree that was converted from a general tree. 
Meaning, the left node of any given node is that node's child, and the right node of any given node is that node's sibling.

My question is - how can i write a method that will take a node and find its parent? (by traversing the entire tree i guess)

thanks!

Comment: This is a very general question. Do you have some sample code for a node that you might use?

Comment: just imagine a node as an object, and Node.hasLeft() and Node.hasRight() are the only methods used, both of them can be true or false obviously. if a node has a left node, it means that's its child. if it has a right node, it means that's its sibling. if it has none of those, it's an external node.

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a list as you are traversing the tree that contains the path to the current node. That way you'd be trading off minor amounts of memory while saving large amounts of computation time.

Comment: You could use one of the posted solutions with a lookabead which means that in every call you simple check if the current nodes children is the desired child and return the current node

Answer (score 0):

Let see if I understand this correctly

It depends on your implementation of tree. Usually tree do not have any cycles and each node have a reference to a child. But again, this is all how the tree is being implemented.

If you are looking for leaf, you can keep recursing to the child of the node until it reaches the base case where child is equal to null.

```
findLeaves (Node n) {
  if (n == null)
    return;
  else if (n.left == null AND n.right == null)
    return n; // A child
  else
    findLeaves(n.left);
    findLeaves(n.right);

}
```

Same thing with root. If the node have reference to parent and we are looking for the root. keep recursing to the parents until the parents is null which means that node is a parent.

```
findRoot (Node n) {
  if (n == null)
    return;
  else if (n.parent == null)
    return n; // A root
  else
    findRoot(n.parent);

}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your help! but i'm not looking for a child or a root, i'm looking for a parent.. so how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
private static BinaryNode getParent(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t, BinaryNode<AnyType> parent) {
        if (t == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (x.compareTo(t.element) < 0) {
                return getParent(x, t.left, t);
            } else if (x.compareTo(t.element) > 0) {
                return getParent(x, t.right, t);
            } else {
                return parent;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think i have to use Euler Tour to find the parent of a given node, seems like Euler Tour is being used in that code that you posted but i don't really understand it.. btw, my method receives only 1 node (not 3 parameters like yours) and returns its parent.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a node class that contains 'value' integer variable. a sudo-code can be written as something like this

```
Node find_parent(Node currentNode, Node parentNode, int valueOfChildNode) {
     Node finalNode = null;
     if ( currentNode->value == valueOfChildNode ) return parentNode;
     if ( currentNode->left_child) 
          finalNode = find_parent(currentNode->left_child,valueOfChildNode,currentNode);
     if ( !finalNode && currentNode->right_child )
          find_parent(currentNode->right_child,valueOfChildNode,currentNode);
     return finalNode;
}
```

you can change it according to your requirement. you can call it as in the example given below.

`find_parent( binaryTree->root_node, null, 15);`

Comment: thank you! but this is my method:

public Position<E> parent(Position<E> v)

where "v" is the node whose parent you have to find and return, so how would i modify your code accordingly?

Comment: ok. The above version is recursive. You will have to do it iteratively in which you will explicitly use a stack. Java has got many datastructures that you can use for example in this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: or if you still want to do it recursively and passing only single parameter then you will have to introduce a `Node parent_node` data variable in your class so that every child will know who its parent is so that you can return it as in case of @lookman's 2nd answer